# dequeueReusableCell not clearing old views on cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view right now that's set up to work like the Netflix or Spotify side scrolling views. To do this I added a scroll view to each individual table cell which held subviews for every item in the list.

The problem I have is that the table view isn't clearing scroll views from the old cells, so once I scroll down a bit the old scroll views start appearing behind the new ones.

I assume this has to do with the way dequeueReusableCell works, so here is the code I think is relevant

TableViewCell:

```
class MenuItemsScrollCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    func setup(for scrollItems: [ScrollItemView]) {
        let sideScroll = SideScroll(scrollItems: scrollItems, scrollView: scrollView)
        sideScroll.build()
    }
}
```

SideScroll - The class responsible for setting up the scrollview and adding individual view objects to it

```
class SideScroll: NSObject {
    var scrollItems: [UIView]!
    weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
}

extension SideScroll {
    convenience init(scrollItems: [UIView], scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.init()
        self.scrollItems = scrollItems
        self.scrollView = scrollView
    }
    func build(){
        for (index, scrollItem) in scrollItems.enumerated() {
            setSizeOf(scrollItem)
            setPositionFor(scrollItem, at: index)
            scrollView.addSubview(scrollItem)
        }
        setContentSize(for: scrollView)
        // setSizeOf(:scrollItem), setPositionFor(:scrollItem,at:index) and setContentSize(for:scrollView) all do exactly what you would expect them to.
    }
 }
```

And then my cell for method (not actually cellForRowAt cause I'm using a slightly more complex pattern, but it does the same thing and I don't think the problem comes from that pattern so I won't post the code for it.)

```
func cell(for row: Int, in tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let menuItemsScrollCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuItemsScrollCell") as? MenuItemsScrollCell else {
        fatalError("Was expecting MenuItemsScrollCell. Got Something Else." )
    }
    let menuItems = self.menuItems(at: row) // Returns an array of menu item model objects that correlates to one row of the table.
    let scrollItemViews = populateScrollItemViews(for: menuItems)
    menuItemsScrollCell.setup(for: scrollItemViews) // Method from first code sample
    return menuItemsScrollCell
}

func populateScrollItemViews(for menuItems: [MenuItem]) -> [ScrollItemView] {
    var output = [ScrollItemView]()
    for menuItem in menuItems {
        guard let scrollItemView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ScrollItemView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as? ScrollItemView else {
            fatalError()
        }
        scrollItemView.titleLabel.text = menuItem.title
    }
    return output
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Table view cells are reused. You need to clear the old state in `prepareForReuse()`.

```
class MenuItemsScrollCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    func setup(for scrollItems: [ScrollItemView]) {
        let sideScroll = SideScroll(scrollItems: scrollItems, scrollView: scrollView)
        sideScroll.build()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        for subview in scrollView.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so important. I'm adding subviews programatically to my cells. I had no idea I had to override `prepareForReuse`. If anyone scrolls their collection views and see their memory jumping up every time, or new views over the top of old views, add this method to your cell! Thanks Jeff